# what syntax is used to select a row after using order function?

Tags: r, subset

I have this code that gets three arguments. It gets narrowed down by state. It then gets narrowed down by condition. It lastly gets narrowed down by rank of hospital under its performance in the condition (heart attack, heart failure or pneumonia). For this code, I am working on the heart failure part of the code so the other two can be ignored. The order function orders the heart failure rate nicely. However, I am having difficulty in selecting the ranking according after that.

```
best("AK","heart failure", 3)

best <- function(state, outcome, num) {   
  #Reads the csv file
  dataTable  <- read.csv("outcome.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  #Passes the state argument to the choice variable
  choice <- state
  stateOfChoice <- dataTable[dataTable$State == choice,]

  #Makes sure that only three of outcomes found in the csv file are selected
  if(outcome != "heart failure" && outcome != "heart attack" && outcome != "pneumonia"){
     print("wrong condition, try again")
     main()
   }

   #using the selected rows from above, return the minimum value of rate from heart attack and then use this selected row to find the hospital name
   else if (outcome == "heart attack"){
     heart_attack <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack), ]
     hospital <- heart_attack$Hospital.Name

     return(hospital)
   }

   #Similar as above, but instead with heart failure
   else if (outcome == "heart failure"){
     orderState <- stateOfChoice[order(as.integer(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure), decreasing = FALSE),]
        orderStateNum <- orderState$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure[[num]]

      ##heart_failure <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure),]
        hospital <- orderStateNum$Hospital.Name
        return(hospital)
    }

    #Similar as above, but instead with pneumonia
    else if (outcome == "pneumonia"){
       pneumonia <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia),]
       hospital <- pneumonia$Hospital.Name
       return(hospital)
    } 
}
```

For instance, you can see that the order function has ordered the rows nicely under this variable due to  `orderState <- stateOfChoice[order(as.integer(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure),decreasing = FALSE),]`for the condition `heart failure`. The third selection should be `#100` which corresponds with hospital name `Mat-su regional medical center`. I am not getting that hospital name. I am getting `#101` which corresponds with Bartlett Regional Hospital.

```
   Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure

115                                                       10.8
104                                                       11.2

100                                                       11.4

114                                                       11.4
101                                                       11.6
```

The data is here:

[Pls click for dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_sKokV1rcnAzjJsbRWqLTd2GL4GqAfHq)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you are trying to do. Furthermore, your code is not working properly and I get the following error:

```
Error in orderStateNum$Hospital.Name (from so.R!hf5Gh5#27) : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I'll suppose that your goal is to retrieve the hospital name number `num` in your sorted dataset. You can replace your current code by this one, at the right place:

```
   #Similar as above, but instead with heart failure
   else if (outcome == "heart failure"){
       orderState <- stateOfChoice[order(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure, decreasing = FALSE), ]
       return(orderState[num, "Hospital.Name"])
   }
```

There were various problems in your code. The most important was the following: your `as.integer` instruction does not make sense, since your are trying to sort decimal numbers. You must definitely remove that. Also, you should maybe not keep your data like this, with "Not Available" making all numeric variables recognized as character vectors. You may have a good reason to do so, but it sounds quite risky.

You should also modify/adapt the other portions of code accordingly.